# Shared Preferences returns bool value of last saved bool - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, sharedpreferences

When I save a shared preferences bool then make a new one that new one's bool is also true, why? I think it gives the bool from the last saved one, because when I restart the app sometimes everything is false, then when I change one from false to true then everything is true. I can't understand why this is happening. Any ideas? (Extra Info: The Database I am using is called Person and that has a bool called Joined which is the bool I am changing, but this isn't that important because the Shared Preferences doesn't know anything about the database) Here's the code: HomePage.dart:

```
Widget listItem({
    required Map Person,
  }) {
    void savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("person_joined", Person['Joined']);
      // print("${Person}_joined");

      print("Person['Joined'] : ${Person['Joined']}");
    }


    return Slidable(
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
              // print("Before update: ${Person['Joined']}");
              setState(() {
                Person['Joined'] = true;
              });
              // print("After update: ${Person['Joined']}");
              savebool();
            }...}


Expanded(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: dbRef,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                Animation<double> animation, int index) {
              Map Person = snapshot.value as Map;

              String? rideKey = snapshot.key;
              Person['key'] = snapshot.key;

              if (Person['Date'] ==
                  DateFormat("d-MM-yyyy").format(_selectedDate)) {
                return listItem(Person: Person);
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        )
```

Favourites.dart (Here I add the `Person` if you have clicked `Join`):

```
late bool joined;
  //
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getBool();
  }

  void getBool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      joined = prefs.getBool("person_joined") ?? false;
    });
  }
```

So just to sum up...Everything is false (lets say there are 3 `person` that was created) and then I click `Join` on the one but then all three is true then all three is in the `favourites page` although just the one should be true. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences is a shared data storage across the app. If you save `person_joined = true`, it will be the same across the app whenever you access the value.

So if 3 people were created, and one person_joined becomes true, it would be true no matter where you access it from i.e. either person 1, 2 or 3.

To make this value `person` dependent, you should save it with a unique identifier of that person. For eg. `<username>_joined = true`. This way, there would be 10 different identifiers if 10 different people join.

Comment: Referring to `Person['Joined'] = true;` when i print `Person` it prints the unique person data that each `Person` has, so it's already referring to unique `Person`, should I still try your way?

Comment: That's also a way to go, but it won't be locally persistent if you want that.

Comment: What do you mean by `locally persistent`? and I'm struggling to getBool and refernce the Map Person at the same time, do you have discord cuz I really need help with this...

Comment: by `locally persistent` I mean, with sharedPreference, your data will be saved in physical memory and you won't loose it even if you destroy the Person object. If you save the same in a map, or the object itself, the information will be wiped clean when that object gets destroyed.

Yes I'm on discord.

Comment: What is your discord name if you don't mind...mine is `Tyrone#1646`

Comment: sent you a request on Discord